# Why is undefined behaviour allowed in C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I have been messing around trying to learn C lately. Coming from Java, it surprised me that you can perform certain operations declared as "undefined".

This just seems extremely unsafe to me. I understand it is the programmer's responsibility not to perform undefined operations, but why is it even allowed to start with? Why does the compiler not catch, for instance, array indices out of bounds, or even dangling pointers? You just end up accessing blocks of memory you never should access, with no (apparent) good reason.

As a comparison, Java makes *extra sure* you don't do *anything* stupid, throwing Exceptions around like hot cakes.

Surely there must be a reason why this is allowed? What is it?

ANSWER: To my understanding, the main reason is performance. Also, Java does have undefined behaviours, although not labeled as such.

EDIT: restricted question to C

Comment: You mean, besides the obvious reason?

Comment: There is a performance penalty from checking the bounds of every single array access.

Comment: because it's pretty hard to disallow it, at least in the past and now.

Comment: The answer to this question is: because this is C++.

Comment: The compiler can't detect all undefined behavior ([it's the equivalent to the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). Compilers will try to detect it when they can and warn you about it, which helps, but C and C++ let you shoot yourself in the foot if you want to.

Comment: Originally for efficiency of simple expression evaluation and so on. Nowadays, with faster machines and optimizing processors, that's less relevant, but now a compiler can assume that UB doesn't occur, and optimize accordingly (e.g. a loop with `int` loop control variable). Another reason is to avoid needless complexity for the tools, e.g. the linker. I encourage you to find existing duplicates of this question on SO.

Comment: Covering both languages makes your question even broader. Please restrict the question to one of C or C++. They are different languages and provide different features especially when it comes to avoid or catch UB. E.g. see C++ standard library.

Comment: Technically, Java also has its share of what (in C and C++) would be described as undefined, unspecified, etc behaviours.    The key difference is that they are not documented as such.  This includes (a) anything to do with threading, (b) behaviour of the garbage collector, (c) certain aspects of object initialisation, lifetime, and finalisation, (d) a number of behaviours of user interface libraries (Swing, AWT), (e) a whole bunch of things related to performance, latency..... the list goes on.

Comment: @Peter Please continue as you're making my day :-) But, to work from what you've already said: The uncertainty of GC makes Java _unsuitable_ for any mission critical software (e.g. controlling a spacecraft or a heart lung machine) that requires a _predictable_ realtime response time. (e.g.) Something must be done at _precise_ time intervals at 100 times/second. But, this might be delayed [for several seconds sometimes] because the GC "just decided" to kick in at the wrong moment.

Comment: @CraigEstey Interesting. "Safe" yet unpredictable.

Comment: You can always run your code with Address Sanitizer to catch out-of-bounds accesses and uses of dangling pointers at runtime.

Comment: @justbourv - Java supports some specific types of "safety".   It is not universally safe.    In true safety-related domains (for example, in which software that has even a small chance of not behaving as intended poses a real hazard to welfare of people), lack of predictability is often a deficiency against safety requirements.

Comment: @Peter that's what I seemed to have understood - hence the "safe" in quotes. thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, most forms of Undefined Behavior represented things which some implementations might trap, but other implementations might not.  Because there was no way for the authors of the Standard to predict all the things a platform might do in case of a trap (including, literally, the possibility that a system would sound an alarm and lock up until an operator manually cleared the fault), the consequences of traps fell outside the jurisdiction of the C Standard, and thus almost every action for which some platform might conceivably cause a trap is--from the point of view of the Standard--considered "Undefined Behavior".

That should not be taken to imply that the authors of the Standard didn't believe implementations should try to behave sensibly for such things when practical.  The authors of the C89 Standard noted, for example, that the majority of current systems of that era would define behavior for:

```
/* Assume USmall is half the size of "int" */
unsigned mult(USmall x, USmall y) { return x*y; }
```

which would in all cases, *including those where the mathematical product of x and y was between INT_MAX+1 and UINT_MAX*, be equivalent to  `(unsigned)x*y;`.  I see no reason to believe they wouldn't have expected that trend to continue.

Unfortunately, a new philosophy has become fashionable, based on the revisionist viewpoint that compiler writers only supported useful behaviors in cases not mandated by the Standard because they were too unsophisticated to do anything else.  In gcc, for example, using optimization level 2 but no other non-default options, the above "mult" routine will sometimes generate bogus code in cases where the product would be between 0x80000000u and 0xFFFFFFFFu, even when running on platforms where such computations would historically have worked.  This is supposedly being done in the name of "optimization"; it would be interesting to know how many of the "optimizations" such techniques end up performing are actually useful and could not have been achieved via safer means.

Historically, Undefined Behavior was a license for a C compiler to expose the behavior of the underlying platform; in cases where the underlying platform's behavior fit the programmer's needs, this allowed the programmer's requirements to be expressed in machine code more efficiently than if everything had to be done in ways defined by the Standard.  Lately, however, it has been interpreted as license for compilers to implement behaviors which not only bear no relation to anything in the underlying platform nor to any plausible programmer expectations, but aren't even bound by laws of time and causality.

Answer (score 8):

Undefined behavior is not allowed, it's just not caught by the compiler.

The tradeoff here is between the speed and the safety. Many kinds of undefined behavior could be prevented at the expense of a few additional CPU cycles.

For example, you could prevent UB that happens when you read from memory that has been allocated but not initialized by having the compiled code write zeros into it. This, however, costs you a whole additional write into a memory, which is entirely unnecessary.

Similarly, one could prevent reading/writing past the end of an array by checking its bounds inside `[]` operator. However, this would cost you a few additional CPU cycles on each array access.

C++ designers decided that it is better to have speed and allow potential UB than to force everyone pay for what they do not need. This approach, however, is incompatible with Java's "write once, run anywhere" requirement, so designers of Java language insisted on fully defined behavior in nearly all situations.

Comment: Isn't fully defined behavior in all situations a bit strong?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Other than JNI, Java standard is a "control freak": either the compiler produces an error, or you get the behavior described in the standard. At least that is what the standard writers are hoping for.

Comment: That's true, and I really like java because of it, but there is some undefined behaviour though - e.g. there's no way you can predict when the size of a `WeakHashMap` may change.

Comment: What are you saying is not true in general. Consider distinguishing between code executed at compile versus run-time. Modern compilers are a lot smarter then you think.

Comment: @FISOCPP Could you kindly point to the language in my answer that lead you to the conclusion in your comment, e.g. that modern compilers are not smart enough? My answer is about compilers' *unwillingness* to prevent UB, not their *inability* to do so.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Smarter, or more smart-alecky?  While there may be some platfoms where integer overflow might have natural side-effects that might not be predictable (e.g. triggering a trap which will usually invoke an overflow-interrupt handler, but might sometimes dispatch to a random location if it occurs at the exact moment a character arrives on a serial port), most platforms should have no problem guaranteeing that no integer operation other than division or remainder will ever have any side-effects.  Unfortunately, some compilers like to use their "smarts" to create side-effects where none...

Comment: ...would otherwise exist.

Answer (score -2):

Java has a run time environment to take care of you. That's why an exception is thrown when going out of bounds - it's something that can't be figured out at compile time.

There is run time bounds checking in C++ when using the at() method for a vector. It's what distinguishes at() from the []operator

Comment: A C compiler produces all code that ends up in the final program. It could easily add code to check for out of bounds access, thus allowing a run time check. Leaving this behavior undefined is not a technical limitation: It is a decision made by the language designers.