# Getting a range error from ZyBooks grader but program runs on Visual Studio Code w/ no problem

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, coordinates

Can anyone help me out here? When I run the program it runs and everything is right but when I upload it onto the grader (ZyBooks) it is giving me this error: "Unhandled exception: Range error: 2" for the function createMatrix. The file that was read from contains coordinate points in (x, y, z) format and is read into a vector of type Point and then translated into a matrix (2D vector).

The coordinates.txt contains:
(1,2,3) (4,5,6) (7,8,9) (10,11,12) (13,14,15)

Thank you, I have posted my code below.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
 
struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
 
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p) {
        char dummy;
 
        is >> dummy;
        is >> p.x;
        is >> dummy;
        is >> p.y;
        is >> dummy;
        is >> p.z;
        is >> dummy;
 
        return is;
}
 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p) {
    return os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << "," << p.z << ")";
}
 
void createMatrix(const vector<Point>& v1, vector<vector<double> >& v2) {
    // Set row for x
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            v2[i][j] = v1[j].x;
        }
    }
 
    // Set row for y
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            v2[i + 1][j] = v1[j].y;
        }
    }
 
    // Set row for z
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            v2[i + 2][j] = v1[j].z;
        }
    }
}
 
int main() {
    // Open the file and read it into a vector of Points
    // Declare a 2D vector of doubles with 3 rows and n columns, 
    // where n is the total number of Points read
    // Pass the two vectors into createMatrix
    // Output the matrix vector to a file named "coordinateMatrix.txt" 
    
    ifstream ifs;
 
    // Open the input file
    ifs.open("coordinates.txt");
 
    Point p;
    vector<Point> originalPoints;
    int n = 0;
 
    // Write from file into vector of type Point
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ifs >> p;
 
        originalPoints.push_back(p);
        n++;
    }
 
    // Declare new 2D vector
    vector<vector<double> > matrix(3, vector<double>(n));
 
    // Create matrix with vector of original points
    // x x x x x
    // y y y y y
    // z z z z z
    createMatrix(originalPoints, matrix);
 
    // Close the input file
    ifs.close();
 
    ofstream ofs;
 
    // Open the output file
    ofs.open("coordinateMatrix.txt");
 
    // Write the matrix into output file
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            ofs << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        ofs << endl;
    }
 
    // Close the output file
    ofs.close();
}
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to Thomas, I changed my function to the code below and it worked!

```
void createMatrix(const vector<Point>& v1, vector<vector<double> >& v2) {
    // Set row for x
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (long unsigned int j = 0; j < v1.size(); j++) {
            v2[i][j] = v1[j].x;
        }
    }

    // Set row for y
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (long unsigned int j = 0; j < v1.size(); j++) {
            v2[i + 1][j] = v1[j].y;
        }
    }

    // Set row for z
    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (long unsigned int j = 0; j < v1.size(); j++) {
            v2[i + 2][j] = v1[j].z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than hard coding the limits of the `for` loops in `createMatrix`, you should use the capacities of the arrays;  see the `std::vector::size()` method.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for your suggestion, it worked! I will add my updated code for the function in my original post.

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524302/why-is-undefined-behaviour-allowed-in-c or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119976/what-could-happen-practically-on-undefined-behavior-in-c. Your program "runs on" visual studio, and doesn't *report* an error; that doesn't mean it's *correct*, or even *valid*. C and C++ have the unusual property that many broken programs are not actually required to break.

Comment: @fengvang24 - You had better posted the working change as an _Answer_ rather than in the _Question_.